# can anyboby write a hello world example for me for grouptabs

Tags: extjs

hi can anybody write hello world for group tabs,I am eanble to do it and facing lots of problem also link from -> www.java2s.com is not working , i want something like this ---->
 [grouptab](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grouptabs/grouptabs.html)

Comment: This is an awful question.  :(  Read the documentation then ask a question if you have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is realized using the TabPanel class.

Goto http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.TabPanel.

Comment: hi i already did but my code is not working at all not even  a  " . "

Comment: also i have developed a lot of extjs but i am confused in this + i am good in catching from examples